# Unable to switch back to the previous rootViewController programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

I have two view controllers on the storyboard and I want to switch between them on some condition (for example, on button press), so I wrote the following code:

```
// FirstViewController.swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
    keyWindow.rootViewController = rootViewController
}

// SecondViewController.swift
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as FirstViewController
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
    keyWindow.rootViewController = rootViewController
}
```

Switch from the first viewcontroller to the second works as expected, but when I'm trying to switch back to the first viewcontroller, it changes for a moment, but automatically shows second view controller then again. Strangely, if I change the "switching" code to the following

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
self.presentViewController(rootViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it works as expected.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you just changing the root view controller as opposed to doing a modal presentation or a push? When you go back to the first controller, do you want to go back to the same instance you came from (because your code is not doing that, it's creating a new instance)?

Comment: @rdelmar Because I think that this is the more appropriate way to change view controller programmatically

Comment: There's no reason that going to the first controller should automatically go to the second with this code, unless you're going to the second controller in viewDidAppear of the first controller.

Comment: You should not touch `rootViewController` property of `UIWindow` after you assign it first time. Instead you have to figure out some other ways to present it. Like view controller presentation or some container `UIViewController` that manages its childs.

Comment: @mstysf, Why do you think you shouldn't touch the root view controller? I haven't seen anything in Apple's documentation that says you shouldn't do this. In fact, at the top of the UIWindow class, it says this: "To change the content your app displays, you can change the window’s root view;" There's also nothing in the description for the rootViewController property that says not to change it.

Comment: Community. I haven't seen any tutorial or blog post that changes rootViewController

Comment: @mstysf any reasons for not to touch rootViewController? I've done a few apps which works perfectly with changing rootVC either for login screen or lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the window's rootViewController, you can do something similar by creating a base navigation controller and using it as the switcher:

```
class BaseViewController: UINavigationController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);

        // You can skip this step if you instantiate BaseViewController in a
        // storyboard and set its root segue to FirstViewController
        self.viewControllers = [FirstViewController(nibName:"FirstViewController", bundle:nil)]
    }

    override func pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.viewControllers = [viewController]
    }
}


class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    @IBAction func goToSecond(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(nibName:"SecondViewController", bundle:nil), animated: true);   
    }
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)        
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    @IBAction func goToFirst(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(FirstViewController(nibName:"FirstViewController", bundle:nil), animated: true);    
    }
}
```

Here, I'm loading the view controllers from nibs.  But, you could easily instantiate them from the storyboard the way you were doing in your example.  Also, you can hide the navigation bar so it doesn't look like a navigation context.